# Regular expression in python to filter the files based on match of string

Tags: python

I have over 100 files in a folder, the file names are as follows -

```
XY1234_2345.1.txt
XY1234_2345.2.txt
```

and so on

```
XY1234_4567.1.txt
XY1234_4567.2.txt
```

and so on

I want to list these files and output them in txt file as filenames:
`XY1234_2345.1.txt`, `XY1234_2345.2.txt`, and so on
`XY1234_4567.1.txt`, `XY1234_4567.2.txt`, and so on

how can I achieve the desired results using the Python.

Comment: I'd use `ls > filename.txt` in the shell.

Comment: @KlausD. That's not `Python`! And it might cause unwanted results if they have other files in the folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

my_directory = Path(r"path/to/my/directories")
my_file = Path(r"path/to/my/file")

with open(my_file, 'w+') as f:
    prefix = None
    for file in sorted(my_directory.iterdir()):
        file_prefix, _ = file.name.split('_')
        if file_prefix == prefix:
            f.write(", " + file.name)
        else:
            f.write("\n" + file.name)
            prefix = file_prefix
```

This will write each filename inside `my_directory` onto a separate line in the file at `my_file`.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply, but the error is -AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'iter_dir'

Comment: My bad, the method is called `my_directory.iterdir()` no underscore.

Comment: Thanks it worked but, I wanted the output in the form - XY1234_2345.1.txt, XY1234_2345.2.txt, then new line  XY1234_4567.1.txt, XY1234_4567.2.txt and so on. the new line should come once the 4 digits just before .1 changes then the output should go to the new line. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully it has the desired result.

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)